# How to change text on a textarea which is on seperate thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtextarea

I have a application that continuously (runs on separate thread) listens on a particular port and opens a Jframe whenever there is data available on the port. I have to put the data received on the port to a text area on JFrame. this is my code below

```
private void startListeningOnThePort(final ServerSocket listeningSocket) {

    Runnable listening = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

                while (true) {
                    //System.out.println("Waiting for clients to connect...");
                    Socket clientSocket;
                try {
                        String readLine;                          
                        clientSocket = listeningSocket.accept();
                        BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                        MessageWindow msgWindow = new MessageWindow();

                        while ((readLine = reader.readLine())!= null) {

                            System.out.println("The message received is "+readLine);
                            msgWindow.getPreviousMessageHistoryWindow().append(readLine+"\n");
                            //msgWindow.revalidate();
                            msgWindow.showMessageWindow();
                        }     
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(IntranetChatView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

                }
        }
    };

    Thread serverThread = new Thread(listening);
    serverThread.start();

}
```

The MessageWindow class contain the Jframe which has text area. The Jframe is shown whenever data is available on the port, but the text area is not being populated. Even debugging didn't help.

I think the problem would be in attaining the textArea reference. Maybe the reference to textArea is different from what we want to set the text.

Any help in this issue would be grateful.

Comment: Swing is a single threaded framework and is not thread safe, you should never be creating or update the UI from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.  If you can, instead of using a `Thread`, you could consider using a `SwingWorker`, see [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details.  If you must use a `Thread`, then you should be using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to sync update to the EDT...

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the calls in `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()`

```
                        msgWindow.getPreviousMessageHistoryWindow().append(readLine+"\n");
                        //msgWindow.revalidate();
                        msgWindow.showMessageWindow();
```

From the javadoc

```
  Causes <code>doRun.run()</code> to be executed synchronously on the
  AWT event dispatching thread.  This call blocks until
  all pending AWT events have been processed and (then)
  <code>doRun.run()</code> returns. This method should
  be used when an application thread needs to update the GUI.
  It shouldn't be called from the event dispatching thread.
  Here's an example that creates a new application thread
  that uses <code>invokeAndWait</code> to print a string from the event
  dispatching thread and then, when that's finished, print
  a string from the application thread.
```